# How to format placeholder in textarea?

Tags: css, haml, sass

How can I format text in haml for old ie 7 using divs?
You see I need suck placeholder text:
[image]

it's an , how format and do such placeholder?

Comment: Can you expand on the question?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the heading, the `placeholder` attribute as suggested in HTML5 is not supported by old browsers and, moreover, attribute values (when displayed to users) are shown by browser-dependent routines that are immune to HTML and CSS styling. But if “placeholder” means the initial value of a `textarea` element, then it can be styled normally in CSS, though with the usual CSS Caveats. E.g.,

```
textarea {
  font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In Chrome, I find that changing the `font-size` affects the typed text, but not the placeholder.